# Decrement atomic counter - but <only> under a condition

Tags: c++, windows, synchronization

I want to realize something on this lines:

```
        inline void DecrementPendingWorkItems()
        {
            if(this->pendingWorkItems != 0) //make sure we don't underflow and get a very high number
            {
                ::InterlockedDecrement(&this->pendingWorkItems);
            }
        }
```

How can I do this so that both operations are atomic as a block, without using locks ?

Comment: Unrelated to your actual problem, but if don't want `pendingWorkItems` to be zero or negative, you should probably use the `>` comparison operator instead. It protects for bugs where `pendingWorkItems` turns negative.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that variable is unsigned as required by the API used,

Comment: @Ghita `InterlockedDecrement` takes pointer to `LONG` which is actually a signed value.

Answer (score 2):

You can just check the result of `InterlockedDecrement()` and if it happens to be negative (or <= 0 if that's more desirable) undo the decrement by calling `InterlockedIncrement()`. In otherwise proper code that should be just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is just to use a mutex around the entire section
(and for all other accesses to `this->pendingWorkItems`).  If for some
reason this isn't acceptable, then you'll probably need compare and 
exchange:

```
void decrementPendingWorkItems()
{
    int count = std::atomic_load( &pendingWorkItems );
    while ( count != 0
            && ! std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak( 
                    &pendingWorkItems, &count, count - 1 ) ) {
    }
}
```

(This supposes that `pendingWorkItems` has type `std::atomic_int`.)

Answer (score 0):

There is such a thing called "SpinLock". This is a very lightweight synchronisation.

This is the idea:

```
//
//    This lock should be used only when operation with protected resource
//  is very short like several comparisons or assignments.
//
class SpinLock
{
 public:

      __forceinline SpinLock() { body = 0; }
      __forceinline void Lock()
           {
             int spin = 15;
             for(;;) {
               if(!InterlockedExchange(&body, 1)) break;
               if(--spin == 0) { Sleep(10); spin = 29; }
             }
           }

      __forceinline void Unlock() { InterlockedExchange(&body, 0); }

 protected:

    long   body;

};
```

Actual numbers in the sample are not important. This lock is extremely efficient.

Comment: body should be `volatile` shouldnt it?

Comment: No, not really. This worked in production for years. Discussion about volatile may take place here but unfortunately is it out of the format of the comments.

Comment: you should spin on volatile reads, and only use CAS when the read makes says its time to try acquire the lock. also, you should always use `_mm_pause` to emit the spin loop processor hint, else you needlessly burn your CPU (and use a non-linear back-off).

Comment: Note that I am not reading/writing the data field directly. This is all hidden in `InterlockedExchange`. @Necrolis, your comments are for those who will decide to write their own `InterlockedExchange`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InterlockedCompareExchange` in a loop:

```
    inline void DecrementPendingWorkItems() {
        LONG old_items = this->pendingWorkingItems;
        LONG items;
        while ((items = old_items) > 0) {
            old_items = ::InterlockedCompareExchange(&this->pendingWorkItems,
                                                     items-1, items);
            if (old_items == items) break;
        }
    }
```

What the `InterlockedCompareExchange` function is doing is:

```
  if pendingWorkItems matches items, then
    set the value to items-1 and return items
  else return pendingWorkItems
```

This is done atomically, and is also called a *compare and swap*.

Answer (score 0):

Use an atomic CAS.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683560(v=vs.85).aspx

You can make it lock free, but not wait free.

As Kirill suggests this is similar to a spin lock in your case.

I think this does what you need, but I'd recommend thinking through all the possibilities before going ahead and using it as I have not tested it at all:

```
inline bool
InterlockedSetIfEqual(volatile LONG* dest, LONG exchange, LONG comperand)
{
    return comperand == ::InterlockedCompareExchange(dest, exchange, comperand);
}

inline bool InterlockedDecrementNotZero(volatile LONG* ptr)
{
    LONG comperand;
    LONG exchange;
    do {
        comperand = *ptr;
        exchange = comperand-1;
        if (comperand <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
    } while (!InterlockedSetIfEqual(ptr,exchange,comperand));
    return true;
}
```

There remains the question as to why your pending work items should ever go below zero. You should really ensure that the number of increments matches the number of decrements and all will be fine.  I'd perhaps add an assert or exception if this constraint is violated.

Comment: Minor remark: Using the standard c++ assert for possible race conditions is useless, because many race conditions will only occur in release builds, and `assert` wont be enabled in release builds. One should write his own assert version for such cases which is enabled in all configurations.

Comment: agreed.  An exception would be better.

Comment: @smerlin if underflow happens for a reason (possibly a bug) I would not want that to lead to another more dangerous bug in my case. It's just a fail safe.